# Repeated arguments in a prepared statement

Tags: sql, perl, dbi

consider a query that looks something like this:

```
my $query=<<QUERY;

select * from foo1 where col < ?
union all
select * from foo2 where col < ?
QUERY
```

Assume that the actual query really needs unions and can't be efficiently solved another way.  The variable in the where clause will always be the same.  Is there any way I can structure this so that I only need to pass 1 argument to execute instead of passing the same argument twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the list repetition operator.

```
$sth->execute(($value) x 2);
```

Answer (score 5):

Could try the following, I'm assuming you're passing an integer to the where clause...

```
DECLARE @variableName as int

SET @variableName = ? --the value gets passed here once

select * from foo1 where col < @variableName -- and gets used here
union all
select * from foo2 where col < @variableName -- and here!
```

Answer (score 4):

In "real" databases, you can parameterize a query and pass in the query as an argument.  Here is an alternative solution:

```
with const as (select ? as val)
select *
from ((select foo1.*
       from foo1 cross join const
       where col < const.val
      ) union all
      (select foo2.*
      from foo2 cross join const
      where col < const.val
     )) t
```

I am not suggesting that this is necesarily a good idea.  However, I have at times found it quite useful to gather parameters into such a subquery and then join them in where needed.